# Gracenote free license users limit

Tags: android, gracenote

In my app app i made daily limit - 100 request for user to avoid applying restrictions on me.
How much users i can register per month and how much request for one user per day?
On the official site a have found no information.

Comment: http://www.gracenote.com/contact-us-form/

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, there is no guaranteed limits for non-commercial Gracenote developers, and is depending on system availability.